# Persist data across multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, persist

I have a login form (created with `Html.BeginForm()`) with an email field, password field, and a "Forgot Password?" link within it. Originally, it was a submit button within the login form, and it would intercept the `SignIn` action. I wanted to abstract the Forgot Password functionality from the SignIn action.

In doing so, I noticed that it was set up this way in order to pass the email field value to the Forgot Password page (so the user wouldn't have to re-enter it). That was placed into `TempData`.

My thought was to have an AJAX call to a new controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ToForgotMyPassword(string email)
    {
        TempData["signInEmail"] = email;

        return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("ForgotMyPassword"), TempData = TempData, email = email });
    }
```

But my problem I've found is the `TempData` doesn't persist to the next action, `ForgotMyPassword`. On my view, I have the following JS:

```
$('#forgotPassword').click(function (e) {
    var forgotMyPasswordUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ToForgotMyPassword")',
        data: { email: $('#Email').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //alert('Success');
            console.log(result);
            window.location = result.redirectUrl;
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error');
            console.log(result);
            //window.location = forgotMyPasswordUrl;
        }
    });
});
```

How would I go about persisting this TempData to the redirect page? Is the way I'm going about this just not suited for an AJAX call? Should I just make a new model and new form within the Login form?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repeat your problem. And here what I done:

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult ToForgotMyPassword(string email)
 {
     TempData["signInEmail"] = email;

     return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("ForgotMyPassword")});
 }

 [HttpGet]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult ForgotMyPassword()
 {
     var email = TempData["signInEmail"];

     return View("Index", email);
 }
```

View:

```
@model string
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <div>
        <input id="email" value="test@test.com"/>
        <button id="forgotPassword">forgotPassword</button>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
  $('#forgotPassword').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ToForgotMyPassword")',
        data: { email: $('#email').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            window.location = result.redirectUrl;
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And all this stuff works fine, so i checked two theories:
1) If you try to send TempData ("TempData = TempData" in next code fragment)

```
Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("ForgotMyPassword"), TempData = TempData, email = email });
```

TempData will be cleared, it will not have any element in it's collection
2) if you input id="email" and in script you use $("#Email").val() - you will got nothing. name should be equals

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In my app, `TempData["email"]` is not available on the redirect page. I have checked my TempData and Jquery and both are getting the right values fine. It is just when I get redirected to the next page (a new controller that I passed back to the Jquery), `TempData["email"]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing, I think the question is about my solution to my initial problem. As stated in the question, I'm not sure my solution is the best way to solve my problem.